# Are Application scoped resources part of the JEE6 Specification?

Tags: java, glassfish, java-ee-6

Are Application scoped resources (java:app/... or java:module/...) a Glassfishv3.1 feature or standard JEE6 specification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Java EE 6 umbrella specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/javaee-6.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/).

**EE.5.2.2 Application Component Environment Namespaces**

> The application component’s naming environment is composed of four
> logical namespaces, representing naming environments with different
> scopes. The four namespaces are:
>
> - java:comp - Names in this namespace are per-component (...) See note below.
> - java:module - Names in this namespace are shared by all components in a module (...)
> - java:app - Names in this namespace are shared by all components in all mod- ules in a single application (...)
> - java:global - Names in this namespace are shared by all applications deployed in an application server instance. (...)

And probably even more interesting:

**EE.5.3.4 Java EE Product Provider’s Responsibilities**

> The Java EE Product Provider has the following responsibilities: (...)
>
> - Implement the **java:comp, java:module, java:app** and **java:global** environment naming contexts, and provide them to the application component instances at runtime.

HTH.

Comment: nice, thnx, so Glassfish V3.0 should implement that, but it seems glassfish-resource.xml can not create app-scoped JNDI via auto deploying! I think it solved in Glassfish V3.1 ( but i am not sure)